# CheckboxTree : lvl1 box | lvl2 radio

Tags: extjs

All the question is in my title =).

I started with checkBox Tree exemple, add property checked:false for the first level that work i see my checkbox just on left icone folder.

But have radio in level that is so different, i tryed some change to transform checkbox in radio, but nothing *:_:*

Some topic given by broogle talk only some levels with checkbox but none with radio.

Have you an idea ?

Thx a lot, have a nice day.

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?50246-Radio-support-to-tree-probleam

Comment: Well, this exemple is extjs3 no ?

Comment: Sorry double post...

Thx MMT, but this exemple is extjs3 no ?

I'm on extjs4, when i try this exemple firebug return me some error, i have comment/uncomment , try some but that won't work ...

i will continue to try, if someone can explain me the fonctionnement of this or have something else.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'm brb on this thread for give a little function. put that on your tree and normaly you have checkbox with radio behavior.

```
            listeners: {
                'checkchange': function( n, check )
                {
                    if( check )
                    {
                        var p = n.parentNode;

                        p.eachChild( function( c )
                        {
                            if( c.isLeaf() && c.get('checked') )
                            {
                                c.set('checked', false);
                            }
                        });

                        n.set('checked', true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n.set('checked', false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/tree/check-tree.html) is using a JSON file to load the nodes.

In de JSON file you can set "checked" to true or false.

```
{"text": "Grocery List",
"cls": "folder",
"children": [{
    "text": "Bananas",
    "leaf": true,
    "checked": false
},{
    "text": "Milk",
    "leaf": true,
    "checked": false
},{
    "text": "Cereal",
    "leaf": true,
    "checked": false
},{
    "text": "Energy foods",
    "cls": "folder",
    "children": [{
        "text": "Coffee",
        "leaf": true,
        "checked": false
    },{
        "text": "Red Bull",
        "leaf": true,
        "checked": false
    }]
}]}
```

You can only have a checkbox in the tree but you can always write your own extension :)

Comment: I need some train on ext before =D, perhaps after my project if i have time i will try it, that could be a so nice exercices ^.^

Comment: The documentation is the key to EXTJS. [link](http://docs.sencha.com/). Good luck with your project ;)